# JQUERY - ensuring only one div ID of a particular class shows when user clicks its corresponding image and the rest are set to hide

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show, html

i have 10 images in a flash carousel thats set up to trigger jquery commands through an XML document

ie:

```
<photo image="images/01.jpg" url="javascript:toggleDetail1()" target="_self">
<photo image="images/02.jpg" url="javascript:toggleDetail2()" target="_self">

etc...
```

when the user clicks an image i want to ensure that only that particular image's corresponding div is shown and the other 9 are hidden.

i've given all 10 divs the class of "toggleitem" and every div has it's own ID ("detail1", "detail2", etc.) so now i need to write my jquery and im a little lost.

so far ive gotten to the point where when i click on an image in the carousel the div i want to show will show. BUT i dont really know what to do about getting the other divs in the 'toggleitem' class to hide at that point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleDetail1() {
$('#bookdetail1').show();}

function toggleDetail2() {
$('#bookdetail2').show();}

etc...
```

do i need to use a .not() selector, an if statement or what? im baffled.

thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: What does the html look like? `photo` doesn't help much, what is the structure of the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case this will help any1 in the future karim told me to do this:

```
function toggleDetail1() {
$('.toggleitem').hide();
$('#bookdetail1').show(); }
```

Comment: since this was technically answered im going to check this as such. thank you karim i owe u a beer

Answer (score 0):

sorry shouldve included the html:

```
<div class="toggleitem" id="bookdetail1">
<span class="cover"><img src="images/details/1/cover-1.jpg"</span>
<span class="spread"><img src="images/details/1/spread-1.jpg"</span>
<span class="blurb">text text text text text.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: strange. user KARIM posted an answer for me that worked like a charm and by the time i came back to the page to click his checkmark and leave a thank u note his answer had been deleted :[

thanks karim!!

"NICE! i got the 1st way you showed to work. once i get more comfy with what im doing i'll definitely try to condense my code into that 2nd method. i dont know if i can mess with the XML without digging around in the flash carousel's source files though.

thank you SO MUCH karim :)"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
<photo image="images/02.jpg" data-detail="bookdetail1">

<div class="toggleitem" id="bookdetail1">
    <span class="cover"><img src="images/details/1/cover-1.jpg"</span>
    <span class="spread"><img src="images/details/1/spread-1.jpg"</span>
    <span class="blurb">text text text text text.</span>
</div>
```

Then run this for all the photo elements:

```
$("photo").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        detail = $this.data("detail"),
        $detail = $("#"+detail);
    // If you want to toggle the show/hide just use .toggle()
    if ($detail) {
        $detail.toggle();
    }
    // If you want to execute additional when you toggle:
    /*
        if ($detail.is(":visible")) {
            $detail.hide();
            // do more stuff when it's hidden
        } else {
            $detail.show();
            // do more stuff when it's shown
        }
    */
});
```